# A website that determines whether there is a solution to a set of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, online-resources

Does anyone know a website that determines whether there is a solution to a set of equations?

For calculus I like to use derivative calculators to see whether my answers are correct and I would to do this with questions that require me determining whether or not a set of equations has a solution.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.wolframalpha.com/?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), graph the equations, and see if there is an intersection point. That would probably be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer once it lets me. What if you are dealing with an equation with 3+ variables? When I enter a third variable nothing changes on the graph.

Comment: In that case, try [Wolfram Alpha][1], it should suit your purposes.


  [1]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D1%2C%20%28x-2%29%5E2%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D4